# Storing parsed lines before converting to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a large file full of log details. It has 100s of millions of rows.

In this file, I have to identify certain lines I want to "keep" and eventually store in a pandas DataFrame for analysis. I'm currently iterating over this and when I find a line I want, I parse the line to get the details and then throw it in a dictionary in the format: dict[time] = {Details...}

I eventually do a pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict,orient='index') on this dictionary.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I don't need to look into the dictionary while building it, I just need something to efficiently hold the data while I'm looping over the file lines.

Comment: can you give an example of the input and how the output should look?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. I don't care how the output looks, as long as Pandas can handle it efficiently. Just assume the lines would be "Time:Thing1='var';Thing2=3;Thing3='var2';}" ... Then the outcome I am going to look for is simply a DataFrame with Time as the index, and my own names for the columns, with 'var', 3, and 'var2' in the rows.

Comment: I was just wondering if building the dataframe as you went would be better than holding the data in a dict and then creating

Comment: How can you efficiently add to a DataFrame? I mean we're starting at row 1 and going up to row 100mm, I think I always read not to add to a DF.

Comment: It will not be efficient appending to a df a row at a time, using a dict would be reasonable in this case and so long as the form of the dict is supported then it should give you what you want. As an alternative if you can read the whole file into a df first, then clean/filter out the data you don't want, that would be efficient

Comment: If you can read the file by `pandas.read_csv()`, then use `chunksize` parameter and for-loop
to read the file.

For every chunk `DataFrame`, use string methods to do the selection.